# You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page

Tags: wordpress

This is showing whenever i'm trying to access my wordpress dashboard, please help.

You do not have sufficient permissions to access this admin page. 
Reason: The current user doesn't have the "read" capability that is required to access the "Dashboard" menu item.

Comment: Is this a fresh installation of Wordpress? How did you do it? Did you use a hosting service to create your blog?

Comment: I installed wordpress from the wordpress.org, manually installed it. I have installed it before 2 weeks.

Comment: Ok so, possibly could be two things: 1. Your database tables prefixes are diferent from the one configured in `wp-config.php`, look for this line `$table_prefix = 'wp_';` and adapt it according what you have in your database. 2. If you installed some plugin, theme, etc. recently, possibly make a role permission delete, so just restore them to the superadmin o whatever user you are using. Check this out: https://shinephp.com/how-to-change-wordpress-user-role-capabilities/